# Counting the occurances of a word in a file in C++

Tags: c++

This is my code that counts the occurences of a particular string in a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>    

int frequency(std::string s, std::string file_name){

    std::ifstream file;
    std::string word;
    int count = 0;

    try{
        file.open(file_name);

        while(file>>word){
           if(s.compare(word) == 0) ++count;
        }

        file.close();
    }catch(std::ifstream::failure e){
        //std::cout<<e<<std::endl;
    }
    return count;
}

//===============================================
int main() {

    std::string file_name, word;

    std::cout << "Enter file name.." << '\n';
    std::cout << "Enter word.. " << '\n';

    std::cin >> file_name >> word; 

    int count = frequency(word, file_name);

    std::cout << "Occurrences of " << word << ": " << count;

    return 0;
}
```

The file is provided in the root of the project. The problem is that I'm getting `0` for any word being counted.

Comment: occurences of words.... is every word delimited by spaces? this code will only work for finding independent strings, for example, it won't find the word `fun` in `funds`

Comment: Yup that's the behavior, I want, but it's not even doing that.

Comment: Have you checked the input file is even being opened correctly? Why do you have your exception handler commented out?

Comment: it worked when I tested it locally and hardcoded the inputs

Comment: That's because it was throwing a bunch of errors. That particular line.

Comment: Also note that C++ streams do not throw exceptions by default. Make sure to turn them on if you want to use an exception handler.

Comment: @MissBlit guess, I'll have to figure that part out. But for now can someone fix my current problem.

Comment: You still need to tell us if the file is failing to open or not. Even if it worked somewhere else.

Comment: You can enable exceptions with `file.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit)`, and since `std::ios::failure` extends `std::exception`, you can print out `e,what()` (though, whether that contains anything useful is another story; in my experience with clang on Mac, `what()` usually just returns the classname of the exception, ie `"std::ios::failure"`).

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you're seeing (unless the file failed to open, in which case read the above comment).

Comment: Doesn't `ifstream` take a c-string and not a string?  In other words `file.open(file_name.c_str());`

Answer (score 2):

I changed from `file.open(file_name);` to `file.open(file_name.c_str())`; and it worked fine.

```
 $ cat file.txt
 hello
 good bye

 $ a.out
Enter file name..
Enter word..
file.txt
hello
Occurances of hello: 1
```

`ifstream` takes a c-string as an input, not a string.  To catch make sure the file is open before reading with:

```
if (file.is_open()){
   ... do stuff....
else
   ... error
```

Comment: Starting with C++11, `ifstream` accepts a `string` parameter. Otherwise, if the OP is using an older compiler, it would have resulted in a compile-time error.

Comment: @Ferruccio good to know.  I do very little in C++11 but this is a welcome change.  I posted this answer because after a copy paste of the OP code I made that one change and it worked...go figure.  Well that and I added the `#include <fstream>`.

Answer (score 0):

With a few small corrections your code will do the job, specifically the *file reading loop* could be modified to firstly read a whole line and then read each `string` contained in it separately:

```
int frequency(std::string s, std::string file_name) {

    std::ifstream file(file_name.c_str());
    // check if file successfully open
    if (!file) cerr << "Can't open input file!\n";

    int count = 0;
    try{

        // extract all lines
        std::string line;
        while(getline(file, line)) {

            stringstream ss(line);
            string word;

            // extract all words separated by white space
            while (ss >> word) {

                // compare with wanted
                if(s == word) ++count;
           }
        }

    }catch(std::exception& e){

        // std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;

    }
    return count;
}
```

---

Few notes:

- you don't need to explicitly close your file stream, it is done automatically at the end, as `file` is a local variable in the function.
- the `try` - `catch` block is redundant if you are only using it to check stream status. You could do it with a single line, as pointed out in the answer.
- it is a good practice for the file name to be a *c - style string* (ending with '\0'). Stream member function [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) performs the conversion.
- you could open the file in the definition of the stream and skip the line containing the stream member function `open()`.